# Retrieve single data from a database with Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a table that looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[loginInfos] 
(
    [loginId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [username] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [password] VARCHAR (50) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([loginId] ASC)
);
```

I want to get the username and compare it with a input from a textbox. It will really be a huge help.

Comment: It's not a good practice to store plaintext passwords in a database.

Comment: so what would you recommend for me to do?

Comment: At a minimum, store a salted hash of the password. Google "bcrypt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var MyDb = new MyDb ("c:\\Data\\MyDb .mdf");

var user = =
(from u in MyDb.loginInfos
where u.username== txtUsername.Text
select u).SingleOrDefault();

// user.username
```

Comment: how can i convert it to string? it keeps throwing me "cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<class>' to 'string'"

Comment: get SingleOrDefault()

Comment: this is what im trying to do

Comment: var usermatch = (from u in dc.loginInfos where u.username == userNameIn.Text select u).SingleOrDefault();

            MessageBox.Show(usermatch.username);

Comment: can you please check usermach object is null